# Getting rid of square root via integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, morse-theory

How do we prove, for positive $D$, this result?

$$
e^{-2\sqrt D} \sqrt{\pi} =
\int_0^\infty s^{-1/2} e^{-(s+D/s)} ds
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=y^{2}$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{e}^{-(x+D/x)} dx &=
2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(y^{2}+D/y^{2})} dy \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-2\sqrt{D}}
\end{align}

To evaluate the $y$ integral, we used the [Cauchy-Schlomilch Transformation](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/schlomilch-sub.pdf), Theorem 2.1 and the actual $y$ integral is evaluated in Example 3.1, equation 3.3.